# Delete object pointer in hashtable

Tags: c++11, pointers

I have a hashtable with chaining where each node is:

```
struct Node
{
    Object * objPtr;
    Node * next;
}
```

When I read data from the file I create an object:

```
...
Object * currObj;
currObj = new Object; //Causes memory leaks (doesn't get deleted)

//Save data
currObj->setData(data);
//Insertion
insert(*currObj);
```

What would be the correct destructor for such a case? I have a destructor for table and destructor for Object, but `currObj = new Object` seems to cause leaks.

**Table destructor:**

```
//delete each chain
int i;
for (i = 0; i<capacity; i++)
{
    Node * head = table[i];
    Node * curr;
    while (head)
    {
        curr = head->next;
        head->next = NULL;
        delete head;
        head = curr;
    }
}

//delete the array
delete[] table;
```

**Object destructor**

```
if (name)
    delete[] name;
if (location)
    delete[] location;
//more if with data members
```

**UPD - Insert**

```
void Table::insert(Object & obj_)
{
    char key[200];
    char curr[100];
    obj_.getKeywords(key);  //Get keywords for the passed obj

    char * token;
    token = strtok(key, "?");    //Ge the first keyword

    //Loop to add nodes for each keyword from the passed object
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        int index = calculateIndex(token);    //calculate index based of the 
                                              //first keyword

        //Create new node
        Node * newNode = new Node;
        newNode->obj = &obj_;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        //Link node and table
        newNode->next = table[index];
        table[index] = newNode;
        size++;

        token = strtok(NULL, "?");    //Get next keyword
    }
}
```

Comment: Show all the destructor code you have already. The second snippet you have above is in Node?

Comment: @MrJLP Updated.

Comment: Use smart pointers (`shared_ptr`) and save the hassle

Comment: What is the code of the "insert" method? The de-referencing operator `*` looks strange to me. (If the method is `insert(Object o)` and not `insert(Object &o)` deletion cannot work.)

Answer (score 0):

You need a destructor for `Node`, which would need something like:

```
Node::~Node()
{
    if ( objPtr != NULL ) {
        delete objPtr;
        objPtr = NULL;
    }
    if ( next != NULL ) {
        delete next;
        next = NULL;
    }
}
```

When your table destructor calls `delete head` this is when the `Node` destructor is called. It will have a destructor by default but won't specifically free/delete the allocated object.

Comment: You do not need the `if`s. Deleting nullptr is ok.

Comment: As @EdHeal pointed out, the null checks are unnecessary, however if you want to make use of them I would recommend setting the pointer to `nullptr` after the call to delete. At least that makes debugging easier if an object gets reused after it gets destroyed - and yes, I know that that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to explicitly only delete when the pointer is valid. Added the setting to `NULL` afterwards. Used `NULL` rather than `nullptr` to be consistent with existing sample code given.

Comment: It still doesn't delete the data. I guess I don't insert correctly, so it cannot delete correctly afterwards

Comment: Step through in a debugger or add log lines to figure out what's going on. You'll need the `Node` destructor in any case though

Comment: @MrJLP I've stepped through a debugger for the past couple of hours. I feel like I miss something really obvious.

Comment: Well, the missing Node dtor is the most obvious problem that I'm able to see. Looks like a problem elsewhere in the code. You'd need to show us the entire source code for people to be able to debug it, but that's not quite what the site is for. As a general tip

Comment: When you step through in the debugger is it allocating and deleting as you would expect? Add some debug output to verify what's going on.

Comment: @MrJLP if I add your code - it crashes. If I leave it like it was(without node "dtor") then there's memory leak. Also, I only allocate memory when creating an object and when creating a Node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144879/discussion-between-mrjlp-and-illia).